# Good user interface for multiple checkbox selection and a dropdown list (View/Editable mode)

Tags: gui-design, layout, checkboxes, drop-down-list

I have a `Dropdownlist` and many `Checkboxs`. For any particular dropdown select value I will show all checkboxs and if their is already any database relation with that dropdown value I have set checkbox `Selected=true`;

The user can also edit ie (*check/uncheck checkboxes*) for a particular dropdown list and this will save in database

Some option what i tried UI looks like.

**Option 1**
[image]

**Option 2**

[image]

Comment: Is the main purpose to narrow down the search parameters or to filter the returned search results? I think if you provide the more general options for pre-search, and maybe the more detailed results for post-search it will provide the optimal user experience.

Comment: You can look into the following component: http://asimishaq.com/resources/tools/multi-select-dropdown-list/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should check http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/. If you have many checkboxes, I think it is not good to show all checkboxes. However, Tokeninput can let users to check multiple checkboxes as tagging. Therefore, you do not have to worry about how many selections in a database. Downside is that users will not know all choices they can select. You may have to use Tokeninput with tag cloud to show all selections.

[image: Tokeninput]

[image: Youtube]

If a user can select an industry, and there are much space to display many checkboxes, I like option1. The search filter of Youtube is a good example for how to represent checkboxes in another form.

Users can select an industry and see all choice he has, but for the second option, a user have to scroll down to view and check checkboxes. You can imagine that a drop-down list which has many items is undesirable. For example, a drop-down list for countries

Comment: Thanks for reply, Well here in my scenareo theres condition that the selected dropdown list (ie Industry type) already have a relation with workcategoryies and so i want those relation to be visible for the user, and by looking at it further user can edit it, Btw Taging effect look cool

Comment: Can users select multiple industries?

Comment: No at a time only one industry, But all subcategory is visible and user(Admin) set industry_X_Category relation

Comment: I like the first option, because users will see all options they have.

Comment: yes i agree even i am thinking to go for option 1, i just wating if someone will come out with new idea

Comment: I added some fancy checkboxes of Youtube, so you will have more idea. I think that checkboxes is faster than Tokeninput, because checkboxes need only sigle click. Tokeninput is slow users down, since users have to move their hand from a mouse to a keyboard and type many characters. I am sorry that I edit my answer many times.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7251/discussion-between-satinder-singh-and-lookchin)